# List.orderBy is getting stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, infinite-loop

I have a `List<Expense> myList` where expense contains 2 fields:  `decimal Amount` and a `Status ItemStatus`. Status is an `enum {Paid, DueSoon, DueToday, Overdue, Unpaid}`.

I was trying to sort the list in ascending or descending order however `Status.Unpaid` needs to always appear last in either ascending or descending order.

Using `myList.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(x.ItemStatus, y.ItemStatus))` along with my comparer worked well.

However, after sorting the list by `ItemStatus` I also wanted to sort the list by `Amount`. So I decided to use `myList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.ItemStatus, comparer).ThenBy(x => x.Amount).ToList()` this resulted in an infinite loop somewhere.

The infinite loop was still there when i removed the `.ThenBy()` method entirely.

I added a static counter to my comparer to try and debug and the `OrderBy()` method used the comparer 90 times on a list of 30 expenses **before** entering the infinite loop.

This is my comparer:

```
class StatusComparer : IComparer<Status>
{
    public bool IsAscending { get; private set; } = true;

    public StatusComparer(bool isAscending)
    {
        IsAscending = isAscending;
    }

    public int Compare(Status x, Status y)
    {
        if (IsUnpaid(x)) { return IsAscending? 1 : -1; }
        if (IsUnpaid(y)) { return IsAscending ? -1 : 1; }


        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }


    private static bool IsUnpaid(Status status)
    {
        return status.CompareTo(Status.Unpaid) == 0;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `StatusComparer.Compare` should return 0 when x and y are both `Status.Unpaid`.

Comment: I believe the infinite loop is caused by the last line in `Compare` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `Compare` is *incorrect*

```
public int Compare(Status x, Status y)
{
    if (IsUnpaid(x)) { return IsAscending? 1 : -1; }
    if (IsUnpaid(y)) { return IsAscending ? -1 : 1; }

    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

Imagine, that we have `IsAscending == true`, `IsUnpaid(x) == true` and `IsUnpaid(y) == true`. In this case

```
x.Compare(y) == 1 // so x > y
y.Compare(x) == 1 // so y > x
```

That's why `OrderBy` may well enter into infinite loop (what is the right order for `{x, y}` collection if `x > y` and `y > x`?). You, probably, want

```
public int Compare(Status x, Status y) {
  if (IsUnpaid(x)) { 
    if (!IsUnpaid(y))
      return IsAscending ? -1 : 1; // x is UnPaid, y is Paid
  }
  else if (IsUnpaid(y)) { 
    return IsAscending ? 1 : -1;   // x is Paid, y is UnPaid
  }

  // x and y either both Paid or unPaid
  // If IsAscending should be taken into account, use it as below:
  // return IsAscending ? x.CompareTo(y) : y.CompareTo(x);
  return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! that makes sense, I'm new to using comparers so just to clarify could I even just add    if (x == Status.Unpaid && y == Status.Unpaid) { return 0; } before the 2 other if statements to obtain the same result?

Comment: @Daniel Mastrorillo: if you add ` (x == Status.Unpaid && y == Status.Unpaid) { return 0; } ` you'll get the rule "if *both* `x` and `y` are `UnPaid` then they are *equal*"